# Variable in while loop not incrementing after for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, increment

I am trying to create a cartesian product of the alphabet with loops. I have for loops that create the desired output but `i` in my while loop is never reached for some reason.

This loop is running forever in a jupyter lab notebook.

```
lower_az = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]
i=0
n=2
lst = lower_az.copy()
final_list = []
while i < n:
    for let in lst:
        for j in range(26):
            strng = let + lower_az[j]
            lst.append(strng)
    i += 1
    final_list.append(lst)
```

Unless I am missing something obvious the variable `i` should increment until it reaches `n` and stop the while loop at the desired length of strings.

Comment: Your n = 2.... not 26, right?

Comment: as blue_note pointed out, the `list` `lst` is re-evaluated in each iteration - as `lst` gets longer in each iteration, the loop runs indefinitely. if you're allowed to use list comprehension, you could just use `[c1+c2 for c1 in lower_az for c2 in lower_az]`. another option would be `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blue_note is correct - Python doesn't behave well when you change a list you're iterating over.

It looks like this is just a typo, though: you've got `final_list` all ready to receive the elements. To fix this, change:

```
            lst.append(strng)
```

to

```
            final_list.append(strng)
```

and drop `final_list.append(lst)` and your program appears to work fine.

Comment: As an aside, C++ and Java also misbehave (produce difficult-to find bugs) when you change a list you're iterating over. Rust catches it at compile-time, thanks to ownership and mutability rules for iterators.

Comment: Thanks, this answer led me to what I really was missing. In the future it may be good to suggest to beginners that the solution to trying to iterate over a list you're changing is **recursive functions**.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the list you are iterating over. The problem is not the while-loop, it's the `lst.append(strng)` while iterating `for let in lst`.